# Match search string with start of words only in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, search

I am trying to implement a search function that when user types into input for a keyword, the list of strings below returns only the results that match only at the starts of a word and not in middle of a word.

For example:
Correct: Input: "of" => Output: "Of mice and men" or "mice and of men"
Incorrect: "of" => Output: "under the roof" //contains "of"

I have tried 2 unsuccessfull methods

Method 1

```
let string = "I have often"
if(string.includes('of'))
    console.log('Match') //incorrect
```

Method 2

```
let string = "mice and of men"
function startsAt(needle, haystack){
    return (haystack.substr(0, needle.length) == needle);
}
if(startsAt('of',string))
    console.log('No match') //incorrect because strings starts with "mice"
```

Basically i need a method that will find only matches at the beginning of any word in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case-insensitive regular expression that starts with a word boundary:

```js
const pattern = /\bof/i;
console.log(
  pattern.test('Of mice and men'),
  pattern.test('I am under the roof')
);
```

To construct this from an arbitrary string:

```js
const input = 'of';
const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + input, 'i');
console.log(
  pattern.test('Of mice and men'),
  pattern.test('I am under the roof')
);
```

Comment: How do you add a variable instead of the "of" in the regex?

Comment: See the `To construct this from an arbitrary string:` code in the second part of the answer. Make sure the string starts with a word character, though.

Comment: very nice and concise!

Comment: do you know of a way to ignore ' such as: men's. So even if there is a ' it would still match it

Comment: I guess you could remove all apostrophes from the pattern and the subject first, if that's the logic you want

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ago but for regular expression :
You can also play with [regex-generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).